# how to move a view from out of screen to bottom of screen with animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have a view which I want to move it with animation from out of screen to the bottom of my screen and reverse! I've tried this :

```
bottomRelative = findViewById(R.id.bottomRelative);
    int widthOfScreen = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bottomRelative, "y", widthOfScreen, (widthOfScreen-700));
    animator.setDuration(2000);
    animator.start();
```

but I can't set a exact location to stop! I want this view to set with 50 margin from bottom!

how can I set the final place of my view to 50 margin of bottom of the screen?

another problem is, with different devices! with above code, the view animate to my screen in 2 devices! but in 4 inch device, is not working!
how can I solve these 2 problem?

I think by setting the right destination for my view, the different devices issue will be solved.

Comment: Hello, you can read about [Translate Animation] in Android (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, that is using 2 views, `startView` and `destinationView`, this way to move `startView` to `destinationView`

Assume we have 2 views: `startView` and `destinationView`

```
int[] startLoc = new int[2];
                    int[] desLoc = new int[2];
                    startView.getLocationOnScreen(startLoc);
                    destinationView.getLocationOnScreen(desLoc);
                    float x = desLoc[0]
                            - startLoc[0]
                            - (startView.getWidth() - destinationView.getWidth()) / 2;
                    float y = desLoc[1]
                            - startLoc[1]
                            - (startView.getHeight() - destinationView.getHeight()) / 2;
                    createMoveAndScaleThenFadeAnimation(
                            startView, x, y, 1.0f, 1, 1000, 300,
                            new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                }
                            }).start();
```

and `createMoveAndScaleThenFadeAnimation()` method:

```
public AnimatorSet createMoveAndScaleThenFadeAnimation(View view, float deltaX,
            float deltaY, float scaleFrom, float scaleTo, int duration, int offset,
            @Nullable final AnimatorListenerAdapter listener) {
        ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", deltaX);
        ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", deltaY);
        ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", scaleFrom, scaleTo);
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", scaleFrom, scaleTo);
        ObjectAnimator fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.0f);
        AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animSet.setDuration(duration);
        animSet.setStartDelay(offset);
        animSet.play(animX).with(animY).with(scaleX).with(scaleY).before(fade);
        if (listener != null) {
            animSet.addListener(listener);
        }
        return animSet;
    }
```

so now we don't care about device's screen size or any thing else, just define 2 view in layout and do this way. In your case, we can set view 2th visibility is INVISIBLE.

**NOTE**

Please make sure whole view has been inflated before do this way, if not, we can not get view's position.

*Option 1:* Using `OnGlobalLayoutListener()`

```
ViewTreeObserver vto=view.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
@Override public void onGlobalLayout(){
  //Here we can get the view's position and view size
  view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
}
}
```

*option 2* override `onWindowFocusChanged()`

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  // Here we can get the view's position and view size
 }
```

Thank @Azin Nilchi for the suggestion.

hope this helps!

Comment: great answer! although I have problem with setting the view out of screen! but when I fix it, you code is awsome

Comment: please note that we should get the location of our view in `onWindowFocusChanged`. if we try to get it in onCreate, it will always return 0! if you can edit your answer, it will be great! thanks

Comment: @AzinNilchi   I updated my answer, in my case, I do this animation after view be inflated. anw, thank you so much !